# Any action at a specific time (MIT App Inventor)

Tags: clock, app-inventor

I am making an application in MIT App Inventor, and I do not know how to do one thing.

For example:

> If - time between (11:00AM-01:00PM) - set label.text to (it lunch
>   time)

I do not know how to do it, do any action if is time from - to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own custom procedure: use a`Clock` component together with the `Clock.FormatDate` method and the pattern *kkmm* to get the time in a format like HHMM, see screenshot.

For a list of different patterns to use, see here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

[image]

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the
 [Top 5 Tips: How to learn  App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)